# is it possible to pause/resume part of a full-duplex connection?

Tags: c, ruby, sockets, select

Yes, no?

How can I achieve something like this:

**In Client side**

```
loop do
    socket.read(MAX_LEN)
    socket.pause_read   # the client is busy, do not send any more data, similar to: C system call shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD)
    # ... working

    socket.resume_read  # the client is ready to work again. 
end
```

**In Server side**

```
loop do
    rd, wr, _ = select(rdsockets, wrsockets)
    # wr is an array fill of clients ready to work
    wr.each {}
end
```

PS: Help can be provided either with C or Ruby.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
The incoming data has a predefined format and the length of the incoming data varies.

EDIT2:
OS: Linux

Comment: Please explain what you think `pause_rd` and `resume_rd` should do. They look like no-ops to me.

Comment: @Celada I'm sorry, `pause_rd` is similar to `shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD);` in C and `resume_rd` is pretty much the opposite.

Comment: Data flow *will stop* if you just stop reading, and resume when you do. The sender will block when all the intermediate buffers fill up. But you shouldn't have to do this sort of thing. I can't make any sense out of 'protect the integrity of the data by not letting the server write to the socket for an undefined time interval'. This sounds like a non-problem to me, or a completely wrong approach to a real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it already works if you don't do anything. The "do work" will take some time, so the client won't call `read` again until it finishes. The server will keep sending data for a little while, until the client's receive buffer (part of the system TCP implementation) fills up; then the server will be throttled and `select` won't return that client as writable anymore. The overall effect is that for a long-lived connection, the server will only send data as fast as the client can process it.

If you need fine-grained control over the size of the receive buffer on the client, you can use [setsockopt](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/setsockopt.html)(`SO_RCVBUF`, *size*).

Comment: Your right. But there is a little detail, I don't know the Lenth of the incoming data so the socket is getting full of data while I'm not reading (thats an issue). I want to stop the data flow while I'm not reading. Also I do not want to create another connection. Maybe `setsockopt()` is the key.

Comment: I'll update the question, but the `setsockopt(SO_RCBUF, size);` approach needs a `size` parameter and I can't provide it since it is unknown for me.

Comment: @Kira again, that's what it's supposed to do. You say "that's an issue", but what is the *problem* it causes?

Comment: it causes a _parsing error_ since the incoming data has a predefined format, that's the reason I need to protect the integrity of the data by not letting the server write to the socket for an undefined time interval.

Comment: @Kira no, you need to make your parsing code less broken.

Comment: ok, I'll accept your answer within an interval of time. If no suggestion is made, I'm going to use `setsockopt(SO_RCBUF, size)` and a fixed length response padded with zero.

Comment: @Kira, you do not need to pad anything or use `setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)`. It may or may not do what you want anyway since there are probably more buffers involved that just the TCP over-the-wire window. You just need to be prepared to read all of the data that the server has sent you and which has piled up during the interval of time when the client wasn't reading.

Comment: @Kira Specifically, you need to either teach your code to `read` exactly one message at a time (this is usually not very hard, if the message contains a length field), or you need to maintain a buffer of your own so that instead of trying to parse a partial message at the end of a `read`, you prepend it to the data from the *next* `read`. If you need more help doing that, ask a new question.

Comment: @Kira I only mentioned `SO_RCVBUF` because I thought your question was about not wasting the *server's* time, not about parsing trouble on the client. This is why you have to be clear with your question :)

Comment: Thank you guys I think I'm going to rethink the problem, it seems like I'm doing it all wrong. Thank you very much.